# Installing git in Fedora Core 8

Tags: linux, fedora, git

I have a very annoying problem with fedora core 8. I am not able to install git it gives this error every time I do a `yum install git-core`

```
Error: Missing Dependency: libcurl.so.3 is needed by package git
```

There seems to be no way of resolving this dependency as FC8 has libcurl.so.4 by default and git doesn't seem to have any version that supports this version of libcurl.

Any help on how to get git installed in FC8 is appreciated.

Comment: How did you end up resolving this? I'm having the exact same problem. You said in a below comment that you used a different version of git. What version? And did you install from an RPM, from source, or some other way? And was it git or git-core?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to kludge this by making a symlink for the missing dependency:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3
```

However, you may well get more of these dependency issues trying to install newer packages such as Git on such an old version of Fedora Core.  Are you unable to upgrade ?

Comment: Didn't work out. Any ways I solved the problem by finding a version of git which could work with libcurl.so.4

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to download the source rpm and rebuild with `rpmbuild --rebuild git-*.src.rpm`.